# Did the Mandalorians have a main blaster in the Mandalorian War?

Tags: star-wars

I am not sure if the Mandalorians did have a main weapon but if they did could you please tell me what it is/ was. I appreciate it.

Comment: From which era? The answer will be totally different depending on the era.

Comment: The Mandalorian war

Comment: @DarthEnd3r25 - Those wars lasted centuries

Comment: ok but I would still like to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most notable weapon used by the Mandalorians was the [Mandalorian Vambrace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_vambrace), a wrist-mounted weapons platform which generally held a pair of fire-linked blasters, paralyzing darts, and a flamethrower, as well as a variety of other useful gadgets. They were certainly not averse to using other weapons when necessary though, and the Mandalorians seen throughout the books and movies employ an extremely varied arsenal.